# PGP: how does the owner of a public key generate the fingerprint?

Tags: cryptography, gnupg, pgp

Consider a situation where Alice and Bob don't know each other, and Alice sends some data to Bob and provides a PGP digital signature. Bob obtains Alice's public key, and successfully verifies that the key was used to sign the data, etc, but obviously he still doesn't really know if Alice is who she says she is / actually owns the public key.

I read that the solution to this is Bob asks Alice for her fingerprint, and Bob compares this fingerprint to the fingerprint he computes from the public key.

However, this is where I am confused. What is stopping Alice from computing the fingerprint with the public key she gave Bob? In that scenario, Bob would do the same computation and then (possibly) mistakenly come to the conclusion that Alice is the owner of the key. I cannot find much information on how the fingerprint is created, other than wikipedia saying that is pretty much the public key run through the hash function. There has to be something I am missing right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. The fingerprint does not reflect any kind of ownership, it is just a shorter but still unique identifier for the actual key. Since the keys for Bob and Alice differ so will the fingerprints. To know that Alice has a specific key it is not enough that Bob has Alice key and can computer the fingerprint over it, but also that he knows that the key belongs to Alice. This information must be shared through some already trusted channel.

Answer (score 1):

The technique for computing the fingerprint is given in RFC 4880, but roughly, yes, the public key packet with some prefix and suffix is hashed with a hash algorithm (MD5, SHA-1, or SHA-256, depending on the version of the key).

Anyone with the public key packet can compute the key, including both Alice and Bob.  The goal of Alice communicating the fingerprint to Bob is so that she can inform Bob that he has the correct key (or, maybe, that he *doesn't* have the correct key).  This is the point of hash functions in general: for example, if I download an ISO image and verify its integrity with a trusted hash, then I can be confident I have the same contents as the party who created the image.  This can be done with a relatively tiny amount of data, which is easier than communicating the entire data again.

Because the hash algorithm will, with high probability, be unique for each key, it is extremely unlikely that if Alice correctly and honestly reports her key fingerprint over a trusted channel, that Bob will use the wrong key.  The same situation will occur when Bob reports his key's fingerprint to Alice.

Alice can full well lie to Bob if she likes, but that doesn't gain her anything: she doesn't learn the message that Bob wants to send to her and she just aids a separate party in learning a secret.  In this situation, Alice and Bob presumably trust each other enough to want to have a secret communication or verify the integrity of some data, so there's little incentive to lie.

Comment: Our answers differ cause I think OP does not understand signature and general while the fingerprinting of the key is a whole different story. Can you add explanation of the signature, I'll then delete my answer and we'll have one complete response addressing all the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a fingerprint and digital signature. No party is proving the ownership of the public key as it is "public", it is available to everyone. The idea of digital signature is to prove the possession of the private key. The choice of trusting the user and his certificate is left to the  user. I'm going to keep it simple.

What you need to prove in such communication is that you own a private key. This is done simply by using RSA (or other asymmetric crypto) and hashing. If you encrypt something with public key it can be only decrypted with a private key. If you **encrypt something with private key it can be only decrypted using public key**. If Alice wants to prove that she has sent a message to Bob she does so by attaching a digital signature. This is how signature is calculated:

Alice

1. calculates a hash of the plaintext message e.g. SHA-256
2. encrypts the hash using her private key (the output is the signature)
3. sends message message to Bob with the signature

Bob

1. decrypts the signature using the public key
2. calculates his own hash of the plain text message (SHA-256)
3. compares the hash from the signature with the one calculated on his own, if they match then message was signed by Alice

In this scenario Bob knows that message was sent by Alice assuming that Alice keeps her private key private and safe.